# Confused whether to used GET or POST when passing multiple parameters to action in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, post, get, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on MVC 4 Web Api with Jquery and Jqgrid, till now I was posting multiple data to my post controller action.

My action looked like the one below...

```
[ActionName("FetchProducts")]
public List<ABC> PostProducts(Product model)
{
    return _service.GetSomething(model);
}

public class Product{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Category {get;set;}
    //.... and alteast 5 more properties
}
```

and my jquery call was something like the one below...

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: /api/FetchProduct,  
data: this.getData(),  
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: callback
});

function getData(){
    return JSON.stringify({
            Name: "from somewhere" ,
            Category: "from somewhere",
            Price: "from somewhere",
            ABC: "from somewhere",
            XYZ: "from somewhere",
            //... and many more....
        }); 
}
```

and this works ! but my friend at work says

> I am actually only getting data and should use 'GET' and not 'POST'. As GET is used to retrieve remote data, and POST is used to insert/update remote data.

and I also feel he is right. So how should I do this with 'GET' ?

do I have to pass all these parameters (there are atleast 10 of them) as query string ?

like for eg : `api/FetchProduct/?Name='aaa'&&Category='vvv'&&.........`

So my question is what should one do in such a scenario ? I would like to know what other devs think about this. Thanks

Comment: Default ModelBinder won't work with the Get Params. And usually personally will prefer to go with POST , since it might not exactly be required but this is for sure going to create problems when the filter data increases. So its better according to me to use POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you query string grows, you will run into problems with the maximum length of the URL, which is browser dependent.

If you have a lot of parameters to pass, a POST is perfectly acceptable even if you are really only GETting data. What you will lose, however, is the ability for the user to bookmark a particular page with the query string.

One case where you should absolutely never use GET is if any of the parameters you are passing are sensitive.

Comment: Concerning your last remark about the sensitive parameters: you should not use POST either. POST is not more secure than GET.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Well not without encryption, no. But there are also things like sessionIDs that you probably don't want to put in a GET since you don't want somebody to bookmark an expired sessionID. Of course, you might use cookies for that instead.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I think Matt's point is that GET querystring parameters get logged on the web server and are generally frowned upon because they can be cached by servers that aren't the host server.

Comment: In this case HTTPS should be used.

Comment: One more thing to notice is in this case is that the filter being sent to fetch the data is a being generated according to the internal code. But whereas if sent through the Querystring its going to be available for modifications by the user. for eg : Page Size = 10 may be changed to 20 , or page numbers etc.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that POST HTTP calls are not being cached by servers or browsers so there might be performance implications. If the request is supposed to return the same data (for the same query parameters) and the overall length of query values is less than 2000 characters, I would use GET.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, your friend is right.  There can also be cache benefits to using a GET instead of a POST.  To switch to a get, you'd just update your code from a post to a get.

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: "/api/FetchProduct",  
  data: this.getData(),  
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: callback
});
```

@MattBurland makes several good points as well about when to use GET vs. POST.

EDIT:
Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvanhouten/6tbxV/) example.  The request that's sent is "/echo/json/?value1=1&value2=2" as expected.

Comment: I have tried this and this doesnt work. My `Product model` input shows null.

Comment: Fire up [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or some other kind of debugging proxy to see what your request looks like to make sure your querystring is being constructed as you expect.

Comment: I just noticed that the url isn't wrapped with quotes.  Updated my post to include those quotes.

Comment: obviously I have done that, and this doesn't and cant work like this.

Comment: Why is that obvious?  I updated my post to include a jsfiddle with an example.  Use fiddler to see that it's correctly building the querystring.

Comment: @Yasser - Model binder wont work for get values. Either u use post , else write a custom model binder for the same.

Comment: @pvanhouten i wanted to do this with single input parameter and not multiple parameter to my action. just in case u missed i have already said in my question about i knowing if i use GET i will have to use pass these params individually hence that made this obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your friend at work. GET's should be used for retrieving data and POST's should be used for inserting new data. This REST convention makes it easy for new developers or users of your API to understand. It is OK that the information passed as parameters in the query string is rather long.  Usually these are just filters that define the query for your GET. If there is one item that serves as a primary key for the query you can just pass it as part of the URL. For example, if Name is a primary key or ID then your request could look like this:

```
api/FetchProduct/aaa?Category=vvv&.........
```

By the way, the syntax for the url will not require/use single quotes and parameters are delimited by a single ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to using a GET instead of a POST.
your code should be below.

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: "/api/FetchProduct",  
  data: this.getData(),  
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: callback
});
```

and action is

```
[ActionName("FetchProducts")]
public List<ABC> PostProducts([FromUri]Product model)
{
    return _service.GetSomething(model);
}
```

Notice：The point is [FromUri].